# How to use a countdown timer to stop a game - iOS [SWIFT] -

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, timer, swift

My game is supposed to be stopped after 60s. But nothing happens with my timer code.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter:Int = 60
var labelCounter:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
```

Here is the code in my GameScene class :

```
func startTimer()
{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0
        , target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer(dt:NSTimer)
{
    counter--

    if counter == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        removeCountDownTimerView()
    } else{
        labelCounter.text = "\(counter)"
    }
}

func removeCountDownTimerView()
{
    scene.view.paused = true
}
```

thank you for your insight :-)

Comment: have you tried pausing the scene and not the view: `scene.paused = true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //calling the wait function 
    self.callForWait()
}

func callForWait(){
    //setting the delay time 60secs.
    let delay = 60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        //call the method which have the steps after delay.
        self.stepsAfterDelay()
    }
}


func stepsAfterDelay(){
   //your code after delay takes place here...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this in a game.  Hope it helps:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startGame()
    }

    var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var gameTime:Double = 10


    func startGame() {

        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    }

    func updateTime() {
        var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        var elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime
        var seconds = gameTime-elapsedTime
        if seconds > 0 {
            elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
            println("\(Int(seconds))")
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just one thing Steve, does have any purpose elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds) ?